# Putting same character in two different position in a string

Tags: python

I have an input string 'java'. I want to replace only 2 '-'s in '----' with 'a' (I want them positioned in their right index) so that I have -a-a.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: Hi.. What have you tried so far & where is it your facing difficulties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want, but from the description you can try something like this.

```py
keyString = "java"
targetString = ""

for i in range(len(keyString)):
    if keyString[i] == 'a': targetString += 'a'
    else: targetString += '-'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I misinterpret your question. I am reading the description as "I am given an input string and need to create another string that replaces all non-`'a'` characters in the input string with `'-'`.

The most straight-forward way to do this is to iterate through the input string and build the new string as you go, concatenating either a `'-'` or a `'a'` to the new string depending on the current character in the input string. See below...

```py
# The given input string and the start of the new string that we will create
inputString = "java"
newString = ""

# Go through each character in the input string to determine
# which character to add to the new string at each position
for character in inputString:
    if character == 'a':
        newString += 'a'
    else:
        newString += '-'
```